# JuJu: How to deploy service to specific machines in "Ready" state?

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I want to deploy juju service on specific machines. And I am aware that I could do this with the "juju deploy --to ..." command. However, the problem is that I could not see those machines in "Ready" state with the "juju status" command.

As you could see, there are 4 machines in Ready state
[image]

And with "juju status", I could not see those 4 machines.
[image]

I want to deploy different services on those 4 machines(same CPU, mem, etc), could anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are right that you need to "see" the  machine in the `juju status` output before you can use the `deploy --to` syntax.

In your case, what you need to do is "reserve" the machine first via `add-machine`. If you want to reserve a specific machine, you run the command like this:

```
juju add-machine maas:netNode.maas
```

For any random machine, use:

```
juju add-machine
```

That will trigger a deploy with the juju agent, and stop there. No "payload" will be installed. It will also give you a machine number, which you can then use as the `--to` argument.

The general syntax for direct placement with the add-machine command is:

```
juju add-machine <env-name>:<hostname>
```